# How to validate single property of a bean at one time in Spring MVC using custom validator?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I need to send a forget password link via email, once a user entered his email that should be only validated. I had only one POJO having attributes email, password, confirm password.

Similarly when user clicks on the link sent, a form to shown to enter his password and confirm password  now only these 2 attributes to be validated. I had only one custom validator to perform that validation.

So is there any way to do that? Following below is my code

`User.java`

```
public class User {

private String name;
private String password;
private String confirmPassword;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getConfirmPassword() {
    return confirmPassword;
}
public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
    this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
}
```

`MyController.java` snippet

```
@RequestMapping(value="/forgot", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView forgotPasswordSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("User")  User,BindingResults result, user,HttpServletRequest request) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("pwd/forgot/index");
    // to check user information has any error
 if(results.hasErrors())
        return model;
    model.addObject(user);
    boolean check = service.validate(user);
    if (check == true)
        return model;
    String status = service.sendPasswordResetLink(accountId, user, request);
    if (status.equals("success")) {
        return new ModelAndView("pwd/forgot-res/index");

    }

    return model;
}
```

when user clicks on the request send

```
@RequestMapping(value="/reset", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView resetPasswordSubmit(@ModelAttribute("linkId") String linkId,
    @Valid @ModelAttribute("user")User user,BindingResult results,HttpServletRequest request) {

    String view = "pwd/reset-success/index";
    if(results.hasErrors())
        return model;
    String status=  this.service.updateUserPassword(linkId,user.getPassword(),user.getConfirmPassword(),request);
    if(!status.equals("success"))
        return new ModelAndView("pwd/reset-failed/index");
    //if Reset Failed
      // view = "pwd/reset-failed/index";

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(view);


    return model;
}
```

Comment: This will not work!! You show us what you tried for this. Where you are failing. You can not assign a task by saying `I have a urgent requirement`..

Answer (score 1):

Your form for password and confirm password after link should look something like the following.

```
<form>
    Password : <input type="password" name="password"/>
    Confirm Password : <input type="password" name="confirmPassword"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="N/A"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And your validator should look like the following where you check the `email` attribute for the hidden value you sent. If it matches then you know you are in the form after the link click in email. If not it is the form before. Based on this you can make the validation.

```
public class UserValidator implements Validator
{

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        return User.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors)
    {
        User user = (User) target;
        if (user.getEmail().equals("N/A")) {
            // Password Reset Form Validation (Password, Confirm Password)
        } else {
            // Password Reset Request Form Validation (Email, Password, Confirm Password)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am making use of springs tag to show up the form and <form:hidden path="" id=""> does not provide any value attribute to set value